# TestNG set of values in XML

Tags: java, xml, testng

I am trying to learn TestNG and want to know if this is possible. I have a String parameter and want to test it against a list of values. For example, I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite">
   <test name="test">

      <parameter name="str1" value="10"/> 
      <parameter name="str2" value="22"/>

      <!-- Hypothetical
      <acceptedValues values="1","2","3",etc.../>
      -->

      <classes>
         <class name="testng.something.com.ClassName" />
      </classes>

   </test>
</suite>
```

The Java code:

```
@Test
@Parameters("str1")
public void testStr1(String str1) 
{
    // Compare str1 with the accepted values in the XML
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to add something to the XML so I can compare the parameter with a list of values and any one of them will make it true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that the alternate and more appropriate approach for such case is [using data provider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders). For example:

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "HypotheticalData")
  public void test(Integer n) {
    // ...
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "HypotheticalData")
  public Object[][] createHypotheticalData() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { new Integer(10) },
      new Object[] { new Integer(22) }
    };
  }
```